# ffmpeg user agent not working

Tags: php, ffmpeg, centos6

I've installed ffmpeg on CentOS and it has been happily encoding files audio files for the last year, no problem.

However, I would like to use it to access an audio stream now, to replace a clunky bit of php code I currently use, but I would like to apply a custom User Agent so my clients recognise the incoming connection.

I've tried -user-agent, -user_agent, and -headers but all three are returning "Unrecognized option".

The code I'm using, excluding the user agent, is:

```
ffmpeg -t 3600 -i http://my.radio.com:8000/1 -vn -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab 128k -f mp3 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/test.mp3
```

And that works no problem, but when I try to add either -user_agent, -user-agent, or -headers it fails with the above error.

If it helps, the version info is:

```
FFmpeg version 0.6.5, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jan 29 2012 17:52:15 with gcc 4.4.5 20110214 (Red Hat 4.4.5-6)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --incdir=/usr/include --disable-avisynth --extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC' --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdirac --enable-libfaac --enable-libfaad --enable-libfaadbin --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-swscale --enable-vdpau --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab
  libavutil     50.15. 1 / 50.15. 1
  libavcodec    52.72. 2 / 52.72. 2
  libavformat   52.64. 2 / 52.64. 2
  libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
  libavfilter    1.19. 0 /  1.19. 0
  libswscale     0.11. 0 /  0.11. 0
  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
FFmpeg 0.6.5
libavutil     50.15. 1 / 50.15. 1
libavcodec    52.72. 2 / 52.72. 2
libavformat   52.64. 2 / 52.64. 2
libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
libavfilter    1.19. 0 /  1.19. 0
libswscale     0.11. 0 /  0.11. 0
libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm answering my own question because after another hour or more of digging, it appears the old version of ffmpeg I'm running, which I got from a well known repo, doesn't support -user_agent option/switch, nor the -headers switch either (thanks Steven Penny).

So, I downloaded a Linux static build of ffmpeg, from the official site. And after bouncing it over the the server via SSH, and remembering to change the permissions to 755, I manage to get the -user_agent option/switch to work.

I hope my own answer to my question, will help others in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the -headers option:

```sh
ffmpeg -headers 'User-Agent: Mozilla' -i http://my.radio.com:8000/1
```

Note that you will get a warning:

```
[http @ 00000000004795c0] No trailing CRLF found in HTTP header.
```

Starting with FFmpeg version 2.8, the [CRLF is added](//github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/5ae1785) if need be. You can
silence the warning if you want:

```
ffmpeg -v error -stats
```

Or you can include the CRLF yourself:

```
q=$(printf 'User-Agent: Mozilla\r\nx')
ffmpeg -headers "${q%x}"
```